# Change sudo pip install library to anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, permissions, anaconda, sudo

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I want to install TensorFlow in anaconda2 and I am not using root. I downloaded anaconda2 and installed in `/usr/anaconda2`. I typed the following command:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

but in `/usr/anaconda2/bin/python`, I cannot import TensorFlow. I found that `sudo pip` installs the TensorFlow in Ubuntu default python2.7.6, so I tried installing it without sudo, but:

```
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7
Creating build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py
adding 'build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py' to scripts
changing mode of build/scripts.linux-x86_64-2.7/f2py from 664 to 775
running install_lib
creating /usr/anaconda2/pkgs/lib
error: could not create '/usr/anaconda2/pkgs/lib': Permission denied
    
----------------------------------------


Command "/home/ds/.conda/envs/tensorflow_env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-THK_wR/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-znMmTV-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --prefix=/usr/anaconda2/pkgs" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-THK_wR/numpy/
```

I have no Permission to write file in `/usr/anaconda2`. What should I do?

Comment: What do you do to execute the anaconda python? You should do something similar to execute anaconda pip but with sudo.

Comment: if i use it without sudo,that will get an error:OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/numpy/version.pyc'.        if i do not execcute anaconda python,how to use anaconda lib?

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda comes with its own package manager called `conda`,to install a package on Anaconda environment and not the default `python` do

`conda update conda`
`conda install <package name>`

in your case:
`conda install -c conda-forge tensor flow`

or you could just add the channel first:
`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

then install by:
`conda install tensorflow`

Comment: when i run conda install -c condo-forge tensorflow,it will get an error : CondaHTTPError: HTTP Error: Could not find URL https://conda.anaconda.org/condo-forge/linux-64/                                           may be anaconda haven't this lib.

Comment: sorry, it suppose to be `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` `it was just a typing error.